# Capybara: Use find to find elements on first level

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

simple topic: I dont want children.

I use Capybara to count elements, which are "first level children" of an parent element. So to make it more clear, I have a HTML like the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="parentdiv">
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <whatever>
        </whatever>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to count the div elements, which are children of the div with id="parentdiv". So the result should be 2 and not 6 or 7. What is the correct approach to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: I found a solution using xpath here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621793/list-child-elements-for-a-capybara-poltergeist-element
but is there a more pretty solution for css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for direct children `>` of the element

```
css: "#parentdiv > div"
```

Comment: perfect answer!